# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '....') - amplify React

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

A bit new to Amplify.
I am getting the bellow error

datastore.ts:416 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
'podcast')

This is my code:

'''
import './App.css';

```
import { 
  PodcastCollection 
} from './ui-components';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <PodcastCollection />
     

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I have a colleague who helped me solve it.

This happens when you have a React component that has the same name as one of your model.
You probably have a model `podcast` and a React component named `podcast`.
I hope this helped